# Testosterone and (Running) Competition

Tags: racing, testosterone

I have had low testosterone for a time.  About 2 weeks ago, my doctor prescribed androgel for me because my levels had gotten low enough that this seemed like a necessary step.  Assuming I stay free from injury (I am prone to suffering it band syndrome), what implications does this mean for athletic competitions.  In particular, I am interested in road races.  If I as a Master's runner were to win a race, what are the implications?  Would I / could I be DQed for the prescription testosterone.  If someone gives examples from related sports like triathlons or cycling that would be helpful too if you cannot give an answer for road races.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would be DQ'd if you were to use it.  Looking at this thread, though they don't mention Androgel specifically, it looks like this is a standing problem:  http://masterstrack.com/2010/07/14233/

The USATF rules on doping can be found here:  http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usatf.org%2Fabout%2Frules%2F2008%2F2008USATFRules_Article2.pdf&rct=j&q=usatf%20drug%20rules%20testosterone&ei=45d_TvLuC-a1sQKgpfgO&usg=AFQjCNFdaNcCSrmM-wHNC1pst2PRUaKE1A&sig2=Kj91Y7RLaSMnK56y1K3ZFA&cad=rja

Comment: Love the discussion from the first link.  Yeah I guess it is a damned if you do damned if you do not for some athletes